# Owl Protege model repository

Tags: repository, rdf, ontology, owl, protege4

I can't really grasp the concept of how I can add an ontology model in a repository for storing. For example, I've created an ontology model in Protege 4.3. What's the next step? Suppose I want to store this model in a repository, how do I do that? Do we need to create the repository locally? If so, which application can be used for it?

P.S. I've just started learning this software and I'm a slow learner, so please be patient when answering!

Comment: What do you mean by "ontology model"? Is it just a standard OWL ontology? And by "repository" do you mean putting the ontology somewhere accessible?

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no sense.  I don't understand 'repository' in the given context.

As in, why have you mentioned a repository, at all?

A little knowledge is a dangerous thing...

I found your question whilst searching for a repository of .owl models.  In particular, I would like to find the UML metamodel, expressed as an OWL ontology, that I can review in Protege.